# Tkinter canvas refreshing

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm creating a frame and showing an image in the frame using canvas in Tkinter. But I need to show images continuously one after another in a loop. But couldn't refresh the canvas. Below is my code.

```
cwgt=Canvas(self.parent.Frame1)
cwgt.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
image1 = Image.open(image1)
image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
cwgt.img=image1
cwgt.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=image1)
cwgt.delete("all")
```

The `cwgt.delete("all")` doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, it is working for me. Can you provide a working code sample with your problem? Or try to use `update` on your canvas object.

Comment: Why do you think it's not working? It's the correct syntax. It simply_must_ be working. You are creating an image item and then immediately deleting it. What evidence do you have that it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The cwgt.delete("all") doesn't work.

Well, not only that line does not work, but nothing else works, so I am showing you here a minimal running example based on your text (not your code) to explain you how to achieve that.

The [`delete()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.delete-method) method performs what you want to do. You can pass it the string ***`all`*** as argument to delete all items present on your `Tkinter.Canvas` widget, or specify a reference to the item you want to clear away.

## Full program

```
'''
Created on May 2, 2016

@author: Billal Begueradj
'''
import Tkinter as Tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Begueradj(Tk.Frame):
    '''
    Dislay an image on Tkinter.Canvas and delete it on button click
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent):
        '''
        Inititialize the GUI with a button and a Canvas objects
        '''
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.initialize_user_interface()
   
    def initialize_user_interface(self):
        """
        Draw the GUI
        """
        self.parent.title("Billal BEGUERADJ: Image deletion")       
        self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.parent.config(background="lavender")    
        
        # Create a button and append it  a callback method to clear the image          
        self.deleteb = Tk.Button(self.parent, text = 'Delete', command = self.delete_image)
        self.deleteb.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        
        self.canvas = Tk.Canvas(self.parent, width = 265, height = 200)  
        self.canvas.grid(row = 1, column = 0)   
           
        # Read an image from my Desktop
        self.image = Image.open("/home/hacker/Desktop/homer.jpg")
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)        
        # Create the image on the Canvas     
        self.canvas.create_image(132,100, image = self.photo)
        
    def delete_image(self):
        '''
        Callback method to delete image
        '''
        self.canvas.delete("all")  
        

# Main method
def main():
    root=Tk.Tk()
    d=Begueradj(root)
    root.mainloop()

# Main program       
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

In case you have more than one element on your Tkinter.Canvas widget and you want to delete only your image, you can specify its id to the `delete()` method because the [`Tkinter.Canvas.create_image()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method) returns the `id` of the image created (this is not mentioned in the documentation I linked to though).

This means, in the above code you can run:

```
self.ref_id = self.canvas.create_image(132,100, image = self.photo)
```

and inside `delete_image()` method:

```
self.canvas.delete(self.ref_id)
```

## Demo

This is what you get:

[image]

After clicking on the button, the image will be cleared away:

[image]